# How to download public-shared file from Google Drive (without Drive API) using Objective C

Tags: ios, download, google-drive-api, asihttprequest

I currently upload some files on my Google Drive, then create shared links for these files. These shared links has forms

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=wAFv&id=[may_be_file_id]
```

I create an app that can download these files. I use ASIHTTPRequest open source library to download those files

```
ASIHTTPRequest* req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<downloadURL>]];
req.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground = YES;
req.timeOutSeconds = 60;
req.delegate = self;
req.tag = filename;

[req setDownloadDestinationPath:<a_video_path_on_Document_directory>];


ASINetworkQueue* networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];

[networkQueue addOperation:req];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(finishCallback:)];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(failCallback:)];
[networkQueue setDelegate:self];

[networkQueue go];
```

The argument 'downloadURL' is shared url of each I mentioned above. But after the 'go' method of networkQueue invoke, the finishCallback is called immediately although the file size is about 2Gb. I tried with another downloader third party opensource but get the same result.

Is the problem on URL or Google Drive has done something to prevent download, but when I paste these URL on Safari on my Macbook, it downloads files OK.

What the problem here?

I just use Google Drive API to download its files.

```
GTLRDriveService* service = [[GTLRDriveService alloc] init];
        GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadURL]; //GTLServiceDrive *service;

        [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {
                NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
                // File Downloaded!
            } else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            }
        }];
```

And it runs into completion block immediately and print 'Retrieved file content'.

How can it be?

Comment: I would really refrain from use `ASIHTTP`, it has be deprecated for years has known issue on iOS 7 and higher. You should migrate to an other library like author of `ASIHTTP` suggested. Read: https://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D

Comment: @rckoenes, thanks for your suggestion, but I already use another third pardty open source named TCBlobDownloadManager too, but the same result.

Comment: My suggestion is go for `AFNetworking` and implemented the error callbacks. You can even to this for `ASIHttpRequest`. The fail or error callback should give you some clues as to why your download is failing. But be aware that `ASIHttpRequest` is 6 years old and night there for not work.

Comment: @rckoenes, okay, maybe you right, I will try AFNetworking. Btw, it returned successfully, no error, it receives a few kilobytes of the file and automatically calls finishCallback.

Comment: @rckoenes, actually I tried other third party, AFNetworking, TCBlobDownloadManager and GTLDriveService but all of them still end immediately. What wrong with it?

Comment: Post the out of either the failure or sucess block.

Comment: @rckoenes, I've just edited my question, I add code download files using Google Drive API, and it runs into completion block immediately and print out that 'Retrieved file content'